# query scope with conditional constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When building a query, if one of the constraints does not return result only then run another constraint

```
public function scopeLatestLocationSchedule($query, $location)
{
  return $query
    ->where('location_id', $location)
    ->whereNull('service_id')
    ->whereNull('end_date') //If not found null end_date then return latest first end_date
}
```

How to write this query with a conditional check on the `end_date` constraint

Comment: If I understand what you need correctly I don't think this kind of query is a good fit for a scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in your model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class YourModelName extends Model
{


    public function scopeEndDateNullLocationSchedule(Builder $builder, $locationId)
    {
        return $builder->where('location_id', $locationId)
            ->whereNull('service_id')
            ->whereNull('end_date');
    }

    public function scopeEndDateNotNullLocationSchedule(Builder $builder, $locationId)
    {
        return $builder->where('location_id', $locationId)
            ->whereNull('service_id')
            ->whereNotNull('end_date');
    }
```

Write this below code in your controller

```
        $locationId = 1; // put your location id here;
        $query = YourModelName::endDateNullLocationSchedule($locationId);

        if (!count($query->get())) {
            $query = YourModelName::endDateNotNullLocationSchedule($locationId);
        }
        $locationSchedule = $query->orderBy('end_date', 'DESC')->first();
        dd($locationSchedule);
```

Comment: The above query returns both null and not null end_date. However, I need to get only null end_date, and if null end_date does not exist then get the not null end_date.

Comment: Updated code. Just make two scopes for getting the null value and not null value

Answer (score 0):

When I have many conditions, I find ver useful to use this snippet before the Controller declaration (just under "use...")

```
Builder::macro('if', function ($condition, $column, $operator, $value){
if ($condition) {
    return $this->where($column, $operator, $value);
}    
return $this;
```

});

Then you can build your queries adding this kind of conditions:

```
->if($request->service_id, 'id', '=', $request->service_id)
```

the line above will trigger only if there is a value for service_id, in that case the select query will search where the id is like $request->service_id.

Hope it helps!